Unity 2022.3 CURL plugin is using incrrect protocol?
public string url = "http://my.ip.address.221/betsinplay.txt"; //
    private bool isDownloaded;
    private string downloadedText;
 
    IEnumerator Checkforbetsinplay()
    {
        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
        {
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();
 
            if (www.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
            {
                downloadedText = www.downloadHandler.text;
                isDownloaded = true;
                // Check downloadedText for true or false
                if (downloadedText.ToLower() == "true")
                {
                    // Do something if the value is true
                    Debug.LogError("BETSINPLAY IS TRUE");
                }
                else if (downloadedText.ToLower() == "false")
                {
                    // Do something if the value is false
                    Debug.LogError("BETSINPLAY IS FALSE");
                }
                else
                {
                    // Handle unexpected values
                    Debug.LogError("Downloaded text format not recognized (expected 'true' or 'false')");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("Download failed: " + www.error);
            }
        }
    }
 

When I try to run it, i get the following error:
Curl error 1: Protocol "htttps" not supported or disabled in libcurl
now why in the world would it point to a non existant "htttps" protocol? My webserver does redirect http requests to https but in the web browser it does so fine without errors,what gives?
EDIT: I need a way to bypass valid SSL certificate in Unity, because this code gives me the same error:
    public class BypassCertificate : CertificateHandler
{
    protected override bool ValidateCertificate(byte[] certificateData)
    {
        // Always returns true, indicating that the certificate is valid
        return true;
    }
}

EDIT2: this is as far as I've got with this version of the code:
 private bool isDownloaded;
    private string downloadedText;

    IEnumerator Checkforbetsinplay()
    {
        
        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get("https://my.ip/betsinplay.txt"))
        {
             www.certificateHandler = null; 
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();

            if (www.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
            {
                downloadedText = www.downloadHandler.text;
                isDownloaded = true;
                // Check downloadedText for true or false
                if (downloadedText.ToLower() == "True")
                {
                    // Do something if the value is true
                    Debug.LogError("BETSINPLAY IS TRUE");
                }
                else if (downloadedText.ToLower() == "False")
                {
                    // Do something if the value is false
                    Debug.LogError("BETSINPLAY IS FALSE");
                }
                else
                {
                    // Handle unexpected values
                    Debug.LogError("Downloaded text format not recognized (expected 'true' or 'false')");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("Download failed: " + www.error);
            }
        }
    }

I got to the error: Curl error 60: Cert verify failed. Certificate is not correctly signed by a trusted CA. UnityTls error code: 7

Really that code produces that error?? why would it have 3ts, it also isnt asking for https, so, it doesnt seem that this would be it.. What sounds more likely is http hasnt been enabled in the project build choices.
